# Using bluetooth framework in Android SDK slows down the system extremely while uninstalling the app

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-2.2-froyo

**UPDATE:**
I figured that out if I close the bluetooth before uninstalling the app the problem no longer remains so there is indeed a resource not released when the application quits.

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is the eclipse project in case anyone wants to try the testapp: http://minus.com/dRRJ2nvzmyN3F.zip

I have built a simple app that receives data from my pc using bluetooth and displays it on a TextView. The app is working fine as I am able to see the received data on the TextView. The problem is while the app is being uninstalled, the system slows down extremely and it remains same after the uninstall is finished. The same is happening while I am uploading a new version of the project using Eclipse. I exported and signed the app to run it in release mode and the same thing keeps happening while uninstalling the app. I have to restart the device eventually. I only came across this situation while uninstalling or upating the app as I said. I quit and relunch the app several times and it is working just fine and no slow down on the system. May be an allocated system resource is not being released but I couldn' t be able to find it.
The device is a Samsung Galaxy GIO(S5660) ,has 2.2 version of Android on it and the app is compiled using minSdkVersion="8". My project contains three classes which are below:

**BluetoothTestAppActivity.java**

```
package com.test.bluetoothtestapp;

import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BluetoothTestAppActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private BluetoothServerThread mBtServerThread;
    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mHandler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                String data = bundle.getString("data");
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
                tv.setText(data);
            }
        };

        // see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16587 for why we are calling this method on UI thread
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        adapter.cancelDiscovery();

        mBtServerThread = new BluetoothServerThread(adapter, mHandler,getString(R.string.bt_service_name), 
                UUID.fromString(getString(R.string.bt_service_uuid)));
        mBtServerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        try{
            if(mBtServerThread != null){
                mBtServerThread.cancel();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("BluetoothTestAppActivity Exception", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**BluetoothServerThread.java**

```
package com.test.bluetoothtestapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class BluetoothServerThread extends Thread{

    private BluetoothServerSocket mServerSocket;
    private String mServiceName;
    private UUID mUUID;
    private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private BluetoothDataTransferThread mTransferThread;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public BluetoothServerThread(BluetoothAdapter adapter,Handler handler ,String serviceName, UUID uuid){
        mHandler = handler;
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mServerSocket = null;
        mServiceName = serviceName;
        mUUID = uuid;
    }

    public void run(){

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            try{
                mServerSocket = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(mServiceName,mUUID);
                socket = mServerSocket.accept();
                if(socket != null){
                    mTransferThread = new BluetoothDataTransferThread(socket, mHandler);
                    mTransferThread.start();
                    mServerSocket.close();

                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                Log.e("BluetoothServerThread run",ex.getMessage());

            }
    }

    public void cancel(){
        try{
            if(mTransferThread != null){
                mTransferThread.cancel();
            }
            mServerSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.e("BluetoothServertThread IOException cancel",ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("BluetoothServertThread Exception cancel",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

**BluetoothDataTransferThread.java**

```
package com.test.bluetoothtestapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class BluetoothDataTransferThread extends Thread{
    private BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    private InputStream mInStream;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public BluetoothDataTransferThread(BluetoothSocket socket, Handler handler){
        mHandler = handler;
        mSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;

        try{
            tmpIn = mSocket.getInputStream();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("BluetoothDataTransferThread consructor",ex.getMessage());
        }

        mInStream = tmpIn;
    }

    public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count = -1;

        while(true){
            try{
                count = mInStream.read(buffer);
                if(count != -1){

                    String str = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("data", "data read: "+str);
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                Log.e("BluetoothDataTransferThread run",ex.getMessage());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel(){
        try{
            mSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.e("BluetoothDataTransferThread IOException cancel",ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("BluetoothDataTransferThread Exception cancel",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the run method of BluetoothServerThread.java as following:

```
public void run(){

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        try{
            mServerSocket = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(mServiceName,mUUID);
            socket = mServerSocket.accept();
            if(socket != null){
                mServerSocket.close();
                socket.close();

            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.e("BluetoothServerThread run",ex.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

Note that I am closing the connection immeadiately after it is estabilished. In this case the data transfer thread is not starting at all and the server thread is quiting(I see it quits using debug mode in Eclipse). So there wouldn' t be any thread left running to block or allocate any system resources but the problem remains as is.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to think that you are creating more than one thread. onDestroy is not gauranteed to be called in general lifecycles so in your onCreate check to see if mBtServerThread already exists and is running a thread. If it does, kill the thread, then start another one. Can't guarantee that's it but it would make sense.

Comment: You are seeing exits, sure, but there could be 3 open threads and 1 quit. onCreate will get called multiple times in your application and ondestroy might not be called at all. Currently that means more than one thread being created and the last one being destroyed assuming ondestroy is called on uninstall